# Azure SQL Analysis Service Not Responding

Tags: azure, ssas, azure-analysis-services

I have an instance of Analysis Service running on Azure, and this morning I lost connectivity after attempting to hook Power BI to my Cubes. I have imported cubes successfully in Power BI just fine with this Azure AS, so I am not sure what cause it to crash.

Thanks I have tried:

- I've tried connecting via SSMS and the "Connect to Server" dialog just spins.
- Within Azure Portal, the service won't load any information and just spins as if it were loading
- I've tried connecting to the service via PowerShell and it times-out

I cannot find a way to restart or even delete the service. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you should open a support case. Can you also try pausing and then starting it though?

Comment: I couldn't even access the service in Azure Portal or in Powershell in order to pause and restart. I did end up needing a support case and they found multiple memory issues that occured that hosed the service. Hopefully it wont happen again.

Comment: Happened to us twice on a basic instance . Resolution was support ticket . Engineers said they found a bug and would apply patch